# Which property is used to indicate that a review was posted on Amazon/Google Play/etc.?

Tags: schema.org

I'm adding rich snippets to an ecommerce site.  They have reviews from multiple sources, but not sure which property is best.  I'm stuck between `provider` and `sourceOrganization`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) property? Its definition is:

> The publisher of the creative work.

The property [`sourceOrganization`](http://schema.org/sourceOrganization) says "on whose behalf the creator was working"; in some way, writing a review on an organization’s site is "working" for them, but I’m not sure if that’s intended like that.

I don’t really understand the definition for the [`provider`](http://schema.org/provider) property in that context, though. It doesn’t really say which "service" they mean (it makes sense if used on the [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) type, but on `Review`?). And why suddenly refering to "producer" (in "the goods producer"), although there’s a separate [`producer`](http://schema.org/producer) property defined? So I’m not sure about using this property.